# Get plain-text password from wp_hash_password

Tags: php, wordpress

When i sign up from desktop in my site. i have used hash password function

```
$passwordUser = wp_hash_password( $passwd );
```

Then it is stored into DB.

When i login with same credentials from my android app in mobile. I have to compare with these password.

How to get original password from DB after using wp_hash_function.

I Studied so many articles, all are says. It is a one way process.

So how to handle this situation

Answer (score 4):

When you login with credentials you need to hash your password again. (i.e similar as you mentioned for sign-up process)

And After hash your password,you need to compare it with password which has been stored in database.

The Above mentioned process is general for the one way password procedure.

Specifically wordpress you can use `<?php wp_check_password( $password, $hash, $user_id ) ?>`

Please refer [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_password) for more detail

Comment: Exactly. As long as the two passwords are the same, their hashes will also be the same.

Comment: @Mohaideen Ismail, If your problem has been resolved then please accept my answer OR let me know if you have further any issues.

Comment: I have coding like this. So i cant use your code..  $resultUser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE user_email='".$email."' AND user_pass='".$passwordUser."'") 

  if( mysql_num_rows( $resultUser ) > 0 )
  {

Comment: @Mohaideen Ismail - For your scenario you need to hash your password again. (i.e similar as you mentioned for sign-up process) & then pass that hashed password in your query.

Comment: I tried that also $passwordUser = wp_hash_password($passwd);

Comment: @MohaideenIsmail, Basically password is hash using password salt, So It may be possible that when you hash your password in sign-up & login time process, salt is different at both time. So It may generate hash password different at both time. Hope You can understand above scenario.

Comment: Understood. But how to design this scenerio

Comment: @MohaideenIsmail, You can check which password salt is used for your sign-up process & exactly same salt you'll need to use for login activity.